# sharing a single service across multiple angular 5 applications

Tags: angular, angular5, backbase

I'm running multiple small angular 5 applications as widgets inside my backbase application. Now I'm trying to write a global service, which is at window level, and share across all applications.

Currently, I'm making the service static and using in each widget and using webpack to create widget specific bundle. Here I was able to achieve http caching with rxjs operators.

But I feel this might not be the right way to implement it. Is there any better way to share a singleton service across multiple angular 5 applications in a single project.

Comment: Is your code at github? It would be helpful to take a look in order to understand your architecture.

Comment: Are you possible to upgrade Angular 5 to 6? Because in version 6 there is a Angular Library feature which ideally fit to your purpose. You can check it [there](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-create-library)

Answer (score 6):

Previously if you want to share something between multiple Angular projects that was pretty tricky. You'll have to do one of the following:

- Create a package contains shared code and publish it to private or public NPM registry
- Create a GIT submodule and reference it on both of your projects

But now I'm guessing the **Library** support introduced in Angular 6 would suits your needs the best.

For details see:
[Angular - Creating Libraries](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries)

It's similar to publish your shared package to NPM but Angular CLI (and **ng-packagr**) really made it super simple.

Answer (score 4):

Technically one of your modules ("main" module) can export its own service via `window` object, other modules ("clients") can inject wrapper service:

```
class ServiceWrapper implements IService
{
    private readonly instance:IService;

    constructor(){
        this.instance = window['myService'] as IService;
    }

    public someMethod():void {
         this.instance.someMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please provide a little bit more code on this ? how to export and import ?

Answer (score 3):

By definition, services are singletons, so if you need a service to be used across multiple apps inside a project, all you really need to do is define it on the root of your project, and import it in each app.module. What is a bit unorthodox here is the idea of using multiple apps. Maybe what you really need is one app, with as many modules as your solution requires. But then again, without looking at your architecture I can't say anything with good accuracy, so if you want to share your code, maybe I can take a look at it and make a suggestion.

Cheers!